# Are Android push API keys associated with app signing certificates?

Tags: android, certificate, push-notification, push, api-key

Our current in-market android apps are signed with the same certificate. If the push API keys are tied to certificates, then that has migration implications for us.

Comment: They are not. What makes you think they are?

Comment: We ran into issues with the google maps api key and our certificate and were praying that they were not associated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it is not like that.it is Assosiated with device ids